# Prove $ \int_0^t \frac{\lambda a_z}{1+\frac{p}{1-p}e^{-\int_0^z \lambda a_s ds}} dz = \log(p + (1-p)e^{\int_0^t \lambda a_s ds}) $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

This question came up in the context of a bandit problem.

Let $a: [0, \infty[ \to [0,1], t\mapsto a_t$ be a measurable function. I want to prove the following claim for $t\ge 0$:
$$
\int_0^t \frac{\lambda a_z}{1+\frac{p}{1-p}e^{-\int_0^z \lambda a_s \mathrm{d}s}} \mathrm{d}z 
= 
\log(p + (1-p)e^{\int_0^t \lambda a_s \mathrm{d}s})
$$
($\lambda >0$ and $p\in]0, 1[$ are parameters)

Here is what I did: Plugging in $t=0$ we find that both sides are zero and differentiating at any $t>0$ we find that the derivatives of both sides coincide:

LHS:
$$
\frac{\lambda a_t}{1+\frac{p}{1-p}e^{-\int_0^t \lambda a_s \mathrm{d}s}}
$$
RHS:
$$
\frac{(1-p)e^{\int_0^t \lambda a_s \mathrm{d}s}\lambda a_t}{p + (1-p)e^{\int_0^t \lambda a_s \mathrm{d}s}}
=
\frac{\lambda a_t}{1+\frac{p}{1-p}e^{-\int_0^t \lambda a_s \mathrm{d}s}}
$$

Hence the two sides coincide for any $t\ge 0$.

The problem with this approach is that I am implicitly assuming that $a$ is "nice" enough to allow differentiation of the two sides. But for general measurable $a$ I don't know how to proceed.